# converting python pandas column to numpy array in place

Tags: python-2.7, csv, numpy, pandas

I have a csv file in which one of the columns is a semicolon-delimited list of floating point numbers of variable length. For example:

```
Index    List
0        900.0;300.0;899.2
1        123.4;887.3;900.1;985.3
```

when I read this into a pandas DataFrame, the datatype for that column is object. I want to convert it, ideally in place, to a numpy array (or just a regular float array, it doesn't matter too much at this stage).

I wrote a little function which takes a single one of those list elements and converts it to a numpy array:

```
def parse_list(data):
    data_list = data.split(';')
    return np.array(map(float, data_list))
```

This works fine, but what I want to do is do this conversion directly in the DataFrame so that I can use pandasql and the like to manipulate the whole data set after the conversion. Can someone point me in the right direction?

EDIT: I seem to have asked the question poorly. I would like to convert the following data frame:

```
Index    List
0        900.0;300.0;899.2
1        123.4;887.3;900.1;985.3
```

where the dtype of List is 'object'

to the following dataframe:

```
Index    List
0        [900.0, 300.0, 899.2]
1        [123.4, 887.3, 900.1, 985.3]
```

where the datatype of List is numpy array of floats

EDIT2: some progress, thanks to the first answer. I now have the line:

```
df['List'] = df['List'].str.split(';')
```

which splits the column in place into an array, but the dtypes remain object When I then try to do

```
df['List'] = df['List'].astype(float)
```

I get the error: 
    return arr.astype(dtype)
    ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: Do you want a single np array of he values or is a new df OK `df['List'].str.split(';', expand=True).astype(np.float64)`

Comment: When you say in place are you just wanting to convert `str` to `float`?

Comment: That command splits each number into a new column in the new df, whereas I would like a single column that has a numpy array containing all the numbers in it. 

When I say in place, I mean just convert the string to a numpy array but keep it in the same column in the dataframe.

Comment: This is difficult to do in place as pandas will expand the structure after the `apply`

Comment: Yea, that's what google is telling me also. It seems like the problem is half-solved with df['List'] = df[List'].str.split(';'). This splits the string in place into a list of string, and then I can use something like np.asarray(df['List'][i],dtype=float) to convert to a numpy array on the fly. It's ugly, but it should do the job I need it to.

Comment: pandas doesn't lend itself to conversion of data into a array-like type for each cell, it's easier when doing this in the ctor, it tries to do some clever unpacking so you have to do fugly hacks

Comment: Alright, I will keep playing with it. Thanks for your help, you have definitely set me in the right direction.

Comment: regarding your last error, all you've done is produce a list of the split strings, you'd still have to cast each element to a float, this is why I did `expand=True` this then allowed me to cast the resultant df dtype using `astype`

Comment: Yea, but it only works if you want to split each number into its own column. However, this does do what I had hopes for:



df['List'] = [np.array(a,dtype=float) for a in df['List'].str.split(';')]


It still gets listed as 'object' data type in the DataFrame, but numerical operations behave as though it is a numpy array in all my tests so far.

Comment: the dtype probably falls through to `object` as it's not categorised as int, float, datetime or bool so if it's behaving correctly then this is just a display artifact

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to transform your data from pandas to numpy arrays.
I used this:

```
pandas_DataName.as_matrix(columns=None)
```

And it worked for me.
For more information visit [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix.html)

I hope this could help you.